# Codeigniter : update records if records exists there or then insert new records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my Table i have four columns .

- r_id
- id (User id)
- v_id (company id)
- rate

All i am doing is to rate the company (v_id) from user.

Suppose, if user one is rate the 1st Company (v_id),Again when same user rate the same Company Then rate column automatically updated. if user one wants to rate another company then a new row will be added in the table. But in my case 
 when same user again rate the company then new row is inserted in the table.

**Model**

I don't know where i am doing wrong in this Model.

```
function ratings($insert,$id,$update,$v_id) {
            // $this->db->where('id',$id);
            // $this->db->where('v_id',$v_id);
            // $run = $this->db->get('user_ratings');
            // if ($run->num_rows() >= 1) {
            //  $this->db->where('id',$id);
           // $this->db->update('user_ratings',$update);

        // }else {
        //  // $this->db->set('user_id', $id);
         // $this->db->insert('user_ratings',$insert);
        // }

        $query = $this->db->query('select id, v_id from user_ratings where id = "'.$id.'" and v_id = "'.$v_id.'"')->num_rows();

        if ($query > 0) {
            $this->db->query('update user_ratings set rate ="'.$update.'" where id = "'.$id.'"');
        }else {
            $this->db->insert('user_ratings',$insert);
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
function ratings() {
            $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $v_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $insert= array (
                'rate' => $this->input->post('click_val'),
                'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'v_id' => $this->input->post('company_id'),
                'id' => $this->input->post('id')
                );
            $update = array (
                'rate' => $this->input->post('click_val'),
                'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

                );
            $this->Visa_mdl->ratings($value,$id,$update,$v_id);
        }
```

Comment: why use a framework if you just use unfiltered data?

Comment: Why don't you just utilize SQL properly, and do a INSERT ON EXISTS UPDATE-query?

Comment: Previously i  used to insert  on exists and update But,As i am asking how one user can rate two different companies. with different ratings.

Comment: What is in the argument `$update`?

Comment: `$update = array (
    'rate' => $this->input->post('click_val'),
    'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    
    );`

Comment: Is that same data in the `rate` item of `$insert`?

Comment: See i just updated by Controller

Comment: Your table also has a date column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your on the right track. These simple changes should do the job.

**Model**

```
function ratings($data, $id, $v_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select r_id from user_ratings where id = $id and v_id = $v_id");
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $data['r_id'] = $query->row()->r_id;
        return $this->db
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->where('v_id', $v_id)
            ->update('user_ratings', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->db->insert('user_ratings', $data);
    }
}
```

The method returns true or false to indicate the outcome.

Your **controller** modified to work with the above

```
function ratings()
{
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $v_id = $this->input->post('company_id');

    $data = array(
      'rate' => $this->input->post('click_val'),
      'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
      'v_id' => $v_id,
      'id' => $id
    );
    $this->Visa_mdl->ratings($data, $id, $v_id);
}
```

Comment: I need little more help about my code.. Whether i dont know the way i am written codes is right or wrong. May be all my codes are working in anyways but i am not satisfied.. Your suggestions will appreciate me..

Comment: You want me to explain how it works? I also see a change I would make - shall I make it?

Comment: No , I mean i just want to know if my codes are working . what should i assume . I mean how would i know . am i written all my codes in  proper way.Cause i am new in codeigniter.

Comment: Well, if you get the results you want then it's working. Sometimes you have to try a lot of different things to get it working. When you have problems, Write and test a few lines at a time. Build a solution in small blocks. There are almost always several "right" answers. Once you find an answer, look for ways to do the same in fewer lines of code. It is helpful to look at code written by others to learn efficient coding. I find answering questions on SO is a good learning experience. It might be useful to read answered questions here and try to understand what is going on there.

Comment: The documentation ([Here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html)) for the CodeIgniter framework is excellent - way better than most. Another excellent learning experience is to examine Codeigniter's source code. It's in the `system` folder of your installation. It's is very solid code. Reading it is a great way to gain understanding about how to write good code and how to use the framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have putted static value of v_id column try by replacing v_id ="2" with v_id = "'.$v_id.'" hope this will help you.
<?php
function ratings($insert,$id,$update,$v_id) {

        $query = $this->db->query('select id, v_id from user_ratings where id = "'.$id.'" and v_id = "'.$v_id.'"')->num_rows();

        if ($query > 0) {
            $this->db->query('update user_ratings set rate ="'.$update.'" where id = "'.$id.'"');
        }else {
            $this->db->insert('user_ratings',$insert);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to remove while i am asking the question . But still it does not work for me..

Comment: Thanks,  why you have putted  $this->db->query('update user_ratings set rate ="'.$update.'" where id = "'.$id.'"'); in update only single condition but  in selecting you have putted two conditions $this->db->query('select id, v_id from user_ratings where id = "'.$id.'" and v_id = "'.$v_id.'"') try to keep both conditions same.